# Crear un caché por tiempo en Angular

Tags: angular

Necesitaría poder crear un caché de los datos solicitados a una API, de manera que durante unos minutos a configurar, 5 por ejemplo, no se soliciten más datos externos. Pasado este tiempo debería actualizarse el caché y vuelta a empezar.

Entiendo que de alguna manera hay que registrar cada momento en el que se accede a la API, ¿debería guardarse la fecha-hora en una cookie por ejemplo o hay otros métodos mejores?

Gracias

Comment: Puedes usar localStorage o sessionStorage

Comment: Perfecto, lo miro, gracias

Comment: o puedes utilizar un BehaviorSubject en el servicio para guardar la informacion, ese servicio moriria dependiendo de el scope del provider, si lo haces en el app module siempre estara disponible hasta que la app muera.

Comment: ENfoca la pregunta en algo que quieres lograr. Si la dejas buscando opiniones sobre cómo es mejor, bien puede terminar cerrada por este motivo. ¿Probaste algo en la aproximación que comentas? Sería bueno que compartieras el código que llevas para ver cómo te pueden ayudar de forma más precisa y oportuna

Comment: Previo al local o session Storage, me he encallado en como ejecutar el http.get de forma asíncrona ya que ahora mismo, mientras se solicita la información a la API, el código sigue su camino, no se si me he explicado. Llevo horas investigando las promesas, async(), await, ... sin éxito. Estoy dudando si seguir en este hilo o abrir otro nuevo específico documentando el código, ...

Comment: Con la información indicada de localStorage, sessionStorage o BehaviorSubject la consulta debería haber quedado resuelta, pero el delay de la llamada a la API que me devuelve los datos que serán guardados en el caché me ha demorado el probarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Este seria la manera de hacerlo con un servicio y un BehaviorSubject

1. En tu componente haces una suscripción a la función GetData() esta te notificara cuando la información cambie en el cache.
2. refreshCache() esta función debe ser llamada cada cierto tiempo con un `setInterval` o bien cuando desees llamarlo.

Servicio.ts

```
private ApiCache = new BehaviorSubject<TipoDeDato>(null);


public GetData(): Observable<TipoDeDato> {
   this.refreshCache();
   return this.ApiCache;  
}

public refreshCache() {
    let cache = this.apiCache.value; 
    let currentDate = new Date();
    let endDate = currentDate.setMinutes ( currentDate .getMinutes() + 5); 
    if(cache && cache.endDate <= currentDate) { 
      this.http.get('ruta', PARAMETROS).subscribe(data => {
            data[endDate] = endDate;
            this.apiCache.next(data);              
      })
    }
}
```